# How to freely draw lines and paths without any functionality in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to use Simulink to draw a signal path, without any functionality.
So, how do I disable all checks? Connect what ever I want, and name it with any names/symbols/characters? Is this possible?
In my opinion LibreOffice Draw or Microsoft Visio are not as nice for this purpose.
Simulink has all the blocks I need.

Comment: Well, simulink is NOT for that... I guess you could try, but simulink is a simulation tool, not a drawing tool.  Dont use your friying pan to make a coffee, you could try and even succeed, but still, is going to be easier if you use a cofee machine.

Comment: You cannot. The Simulink editor is not a standalone drawing application, but rather a tool for programming. So you cannot eliminate the programming part from it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, Simulink is just not made for that. But you can use external applications like **Inkscape** (Open Source) or **Adobe Illustrator** (maybe MS Visio works as well) etc. All you need is a vector graphic of your Simulink Model.

You can get that for example by:

```
print -sMyModelname -dpdf -r300 model.pdf
```

or more generic:

```
modelname = 'myModel';
format = 'pdf';         %// or 'svg' or whatever
resolution = '300';     %// vector graphics do not really have a resolution,
                        %// but this way linewidth and canvas size are determined

filename = 'myModel.pdf';

print( ['-s' modelname], ['-d' format] , ['-r' resolution] , filename );
```

Now you easily can connect the blocks with splines as you wish and changed block annotations.

---

Apart from that: in a serious scientific context there is almost now way around [**Latex+Tikz**](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/).

Comment: Nice, I didn't thought about this option. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Old post, still relevant.

Take for example Simscape or the older Power Systems toolbox.

They provide in/out ("physical") pins, allowing arbitrary connection of blocks, without classic Simulink checks if outputs are connected to outputs.

Without too much imagination, checks common in all "physical" toolboxes like

```
set_param(modelName, 'PhysicalModelingChecksum', '101269080');
```

are good for more than data integrity.

Someone else able to implement arbitrary connections, anyone?